# Random Sampling Work orders in Maximo

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to randomly sample work orders in Maximo based on one good data.  Currently we input around 10,000 work order every month and would like to sample around 300, based on 1 perfect work order.

Is random sampling possible in SQL.  If yes, What is the code to Random Sample?

Comment: What do you consider "one good data"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`sample` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2065953) to get a random sampling of data

```
select * 
  from table_name sample (3)
```

will return roughly 3% of the rows in `table_name`.

I'm not completely sure that I understand exactly how that relates to the "based on 1 perfect work order" in your question, though.  There are a number of restrictions on `sample` that often make it difficult to exploit.  You can always revert to the slower but more flexible method of ordering by `dbms_random.value` and getting the first n rows

```
select *
  from (select <<columns>>
          from <<something complicated>>
         order by dbms_random.value)
 where rownum <= 300
```